# Manual Validation against variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there a way, for a given variable, to call existing validation functions against it?

I'm doing some additional manual validations in model binder, it would be nice, rather than doing:

```
if (Session["abc"] != "blah")
{
ModelState.AddModelError("", "whoops");
}
```

If I could somehow wire up to test said variable against a validator, so it would be more like:

```
var X = new Validatable(Session["abc"]);
X.addValidation(new RequiredAttribute());
X.addValidation(new RegexAttribute(some regex));

X.Validate()
```

which would add to ModelState error dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `IValidatableObject` on your ViewModel, this will set the errors in the ModelState dictionary on Model Binding. Then reuse the existing `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` attributes for your implementation.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web;

public class MyViewModel : IValidatableObject {

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {

        var sessionValue = HttpContext.Current.Session["abc"];

        yield return new RequiredAttribute {
            ErrorMessage = "error message: required"
        }.GetValidationResult(sessionValue, validationContext);

        const string pattern = "^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$";
        yield return new RegularExpressionAttribute(pattern) {
            ErrorMessage = "error message: regex"
        }.GetValidationResult(sessionValue, validationContext);
    }
}
```